# Cannot connect front-end template to node-template in Substrate

Tags: substrate, polkadot

So, I installed everything as directed in the documentation, both the node-template and front-end template. Then, I went on to run `./target/release/node-template --dev --tmp` in the node-template directory, which worked fine and was able to produce blocks. After opening a new terminal and moving to the front-end template, I used the command `yarn start`. This didn't produce any error and I was redirected to https://localhost:8000/front-end-template. The site took too much time to load and I was not able to see the Polkadot UI. Looks like the front end could not be integrated with the node-template.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, which tutorial are you following? Is the page throwing any errors after taking too much time to load? Have you tried connecting the official polkadot JS UI to it to see if it works? (go to https://polkadot.js.org/apps, and in the top left network selector select development -> local node)

Comment: I was following this tutorial https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/ . The site did not throw any error, just connection timeout. Yes, I tried connecting it to polkadot UI, but the local node in Polkadot UI was using 9944 port whereas the front end was using port 8000.

Comment: Maybe, I need to change the Polkadot UI localnode port from 9944 to 8000, but the point is, that https://localhost:8000/front-end-template should have worked by itself.

Comment: You should not need to use the Polkadot UI at all if you are using the front-end template. Can you try removing the trailing `/front-end-template` and try just connecting to `https://localhost:8000`? Do you see any errors in your browser's terminal?

Comment: I tried removing the trailing part. But, it did not seem to work

Comment: Port 8000 is what the front end runs on. Port 9944 is what the node runs on. The two are unrelated. You should be able to check if you can connect to the node by using polkadot.js.org/apps as stated above, that way we can make sure the problem is in the front end template. You should also try running the front end template on another port - it might be prevented from loading because something else is already using port 8000.

Answer (score 1):

In the front-end template directory while the node-template is running,

- run `yarn install` and after everything works well then `yarn start`
- OR, remove the front-end template and clone a new one if you didn't make significant changes to old one.
- OR, stop the node-template and run this command `./target/release/node-template purge-chain` then start the front-end.

I used do these and get this problem fixed, quickly!